# How to mathematically prove that we are sampling from same distributions?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, sampling, monte-carlo

The content of this question is about rigorously proving something which is otherwise considered easily correct intuitively.

Let's assume we have a multivariate distribution $g(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ over the variables $x_{1:n}$. Let's assume that we  know how to sample from that distribution, too. We draw samples $x^{1}_{1:n},x^{2}_{1:n}, ... ,x^{N}_{1:n}$ from this distribution.

Then we assume that we have the distributions $f_{1}(x_1), f_{2}(x_2|x_1),f_{3}(x_3|x_2,x_1),...,f_n(x_n|x_{1:n})$ which is equal to $g(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) = f_{1}(x_1)f_{2}(x_2|x_1)f_{3}(x_3|x_2,x_1),...,f_n(x_n|x_{1:n})$ by the chain rule of probabilities. Now, for each sample $x^{i}_{1:n}$ we first sample $x^{i}_{1}$ from $f_{1}(x_1)$, then $x^{i}_{2}$ from $f_{2}(x_2|x_1)$ up to $x^{i}_{N}$ from $f_n(x_n|x_{1:n})$. We again obtain $N$ samples.

Intuitively we know that the first $N$ samples which come from $g(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ and second $N$ samples each of which sequentially come from $f_{1}(x_1),f_{2}(x_2|x_1),f_{3}(x_3|x_2,x_1),...,f_n(x_n|x_{1:n})$ are identically distributed. But how can we show this fact in a mathematically rigorous way? I could not think of any procedure and became stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the fact that you are equating the two distribution functions, you have, in effect, proved that the samples come from the same distribution.  The probability that a random vector is in a measurable set is identical in each case.

As a practical matter, the question arises whether numerically generated samples, for example in Monte Carlo simulation, are from the same distribution. That can be answered only in terms of a statistical confidence level.  In other words, if you generated two samples using algorithms based on the different representations of the distributions you propose, then you can accept or reject a hypothesis that they come from the same distribution to some degree of confidence using any of a number of statistical tests.  The Kolmogorov-Smirnov test is an example.

This line of thought leads us to the question of how one numerically generates a sample from a specified distribution.  As it turns out the distribution specified by the chain of conditional probabilities is what is used.

For example, suppose we consider a multivariate normal distribution. In step one we generate a sequence of independent uniformly distributed numbers $u_1, u_2, u_3, ...$ using a random-number generator. We then transform these into a sequence from the desired distribution by considering the inverse of each conditional distribution.  In other words, the first sample is the inverse marginal distribution evaluated at the first uniformly distributed number:

$$ x_1 = f_1^{-1}(u_1)$$

The second sample $x_1$ is the transformation of the second uniformly distributed number using an inverse of the conditional distribution:

$$ x_2 = f_2^{-1}(u_1|x_2).$$

And so on ...

To understand this better, consider how the Cholesky decompisition when sampling from a bivariate joint normal distribution, $f(x_1,x_2)$, where the correlation between the random components is $\rho$.  First we generate two uniform random numbers $u_1$ and $u_2$.  Then we apply the inverse of the marginal distribution -- a univariate normal distribution which turns out to be $f_1$ as described above.  This transforms the independent uniform random numbers into independent normal random numbers:

$$z_1 = f_1^{-1}(u_1), \ \ \ z_2 = f_1^{-1}(u_2). $$

Finally we map the independent normal random numbers into normal random numbers with the approriate correlation:

$$ x_1 = z_1, \ \ \  x_2 = \rho z_1 + \sqrt{1 - \rho^2}z_2 . $$

Notice that the generation of $x_2$ depends on $x_1$. Hence, in practice, when we set out to sample from $f(x_1,x_2)$ and impose the desired correlation structure, we are first sampling from $f_1(x_1)$ and then from $f_2(x_2|x_1)$.

Comment: "From the fact that you are equating the two distribution functions, you have, in effect, proved that the samples come from the same distribution. The probability that a random vector is in a measurable set is identical in each case." Does this mean, in other words, that the probability of sampling a $x_{1:n}$ in both distributions is equal? I lack measure theoretic background, so can you describe what does a measurable set means here?

Comment: @UfukCanBiçici: I mean measurable set of the underlying probability space, in other words a set of outcomes on which which probability is defined -- and can be measured. So in practice as we sample from a cont. dist. - we dont have any information until we collect enough points to start counting the occupancy of various ranges of outcomes. You are characterizing the same distribution by your reresenatations above.

Comment: My point here: you already say $g(x_1,...,x_n) = f_1(x_1)f_2(x_2|x_1)...$ justified by the chain rule of probabilities so you have the proof they are the same distribution. Now to sample numerically from $g$ most algorithms I know proceed sequentially as I said to incorporate the dependence using your conditional representation.  This is why I thought this an excellent question -- because it leads to that revelation.

Comment: To understand that better, by saying "The probability that a random vector is in a measurable set is identical in each case." you mean that the probability measure for an $n$ dimensional interval, say $I$, in the same probability space is the same both for $g$ and $f_1,f_2,...$ distributions, am I right?

Comment: Yes you are correct -- the probability that vectors sampled from each of the two distributions fall in the same n-dimensional rectangle is the same -- meausure theory just extends the class of events to include sets that may not be so easy to visualize.  But n-dimensional intervals are what we would  consider in checking if the numerically generated samples come form the same distribution.  If this has been any help - please accept the answer.  Thanks.